# Polarization form / wedge product on cohomology of compact riemann surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In reading about jacobians, polarizations and the Torelli theorem I came across the definition of the polarization pairing on a compact Kahler manifold $(M,\omega)$ given by
$$
Q_k : H^k(M,\mathbb{C}) \times H^k(M,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}
$$
where
$$
Q_k(\alpha,\beta) = (-1)^{k(k-1)/2} \int_M \alpha \wedge \beta \wedge \omega^{n-k}.
$$
I'd like to understand the case of compact Riemann surfaces first, i.e. $k=1$, in which case I just get
$$
\int_M \alpha \wedge \beta,
$$
but I am not sure how to understand this integral. Namely if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two holomorphic forms then surely the integral is $0$. Could you shed some light on what is meant by this integral please?

Comment: You're observation is right, but there are more than just holomorphic forms in $H^1(C,\mathbb C)$ for a Riemann surface $C.$

Comment: $H^1(C,\mathbb{C})=H^{0,1}\oplus H^{1,0}$